# Problem installing mssql-tools "ODBC Driver 17"

Tags: sql-server, linux, ubuntu, sql-server-tools

Whenever I try to `apt-get install mssql-tools`, I get,

```
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 302749 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../msodbcsql17_17.0.1.1-1_amd64.deb ...
Installation failed, ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server detected!
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/msodbcsql17_17.0.1.1-1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1
Selecting previously unselected package mssql-tools.
Preparing to unpack .../mssql-tools_17.0.1.1-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mssql-tools (17.0.1.1-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/msodbcsql17_17.0.1.1-1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I've tried removing `/usr/lib/libmsodbcsql-17.so` and also removing `odbcinst.ini`,

```
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/msodbcsql17_17.0.1.1-1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/libmsodbcsql-17.so', which is also in package msodbcsql 17.0.1.1-1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/a/901877/18822),

```
sudo dpkg -P msodbcsql
sudo apt -f install
```